# Error with glmmTMB can't call FreeAdFunObject?

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I'm running R 4.02 and RStudio 1.3.1073. I'm having an error when I'm running a model with glmmTMB. Should I update or revert to a different version?

> Error in .Call("FreeADFunObject", ptr, PACKAGE = DLL) :
> "FreeADFunObject" not available for .Call() for package "glmmTMB"

I also get this error when I'm installing:

> Error in .Call("FreeADFunObject", ptr, PACKAGE = DLL) :
> "FreeADFunObject" not available for .Call() for package "glmmTMB"
> trying URL
> 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/glmmTMB_1.0.2.1.tgz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 11403989 bytes (10.9 MB)

Comment: can we see `packageVersion("glmmTMB"); packageVersion("TMB")` please?  Does the discussion [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/615) help?

Comment: I have tried reinstalling from the source but the error persists. packageVersion("glmmTMB"): ‘1.0.2.1’; packageVersion("TMB"): ‘1.7.18’.

Comment: FYI, I was getting this error using 1.0.2 - reinstalled from github, and things worked again.

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue. Did you resolve it?

Comment: Me too.  Just deleted my entire R install and started over from cran but I still get the same error as OP. 1.0.2.1 and 1.7.18; R 4.0.2; RStudio 1.3.1093; macOS Catalina 10.15.6. I reinstalled both TMB and glmmTMB.  install.packages("glmmTMB", type="source")  I'm not sure what to reinstall from here.

Comment: update: got this working again by being sure to install TMB first, and then glmmTMB.  (I haven't gone back and done this both ways to confirm that this was the problem, though)

Comment: Got the same problem. Didn't have `TMB` installed, only `glmmTMB`. Restarted R, frist thing ran `install.packages("glmmTMB", type="source")` and the problem was resolved.